# Conditionally include/exclude elements in builder

Tags: java, builder

I have this bulider method:

```
public static QuoteDetails quoteDetailsForMA(String response) {
  handleErrors(response);
  try {
    FullResponse quoteDetails = extractResponse(response);
    Summary summary = summaryMA(quoteDetails);
    List<PenaltyElement> penalties = retrievePenalties(quoteDetails);
    return QuoteDetails.builder()
        .priceSummary(summary)
        .penalties(penalties)
        .build();
  } catch (Exception e) {
    LOGGER.error(
        "Exception thrown response: {}",
        e.getMessage());
  }
}
```

`penalties` may or may not be an empty list. If it is not empty I wish to execute the return statement as it currently is(with `.penalties(penalties)`. However, If `penalties` is an empty list I wish to exclude it from my return. E.g. I wish to return this:

```
return QuoteDetails.builder()
    .priceSummary(summary)
    .build();
```

Is this possible and if so, how is it done?

Comment: Obviously that's doable. But wouldn't it be better to have an empty `List` instead of `null`, which will force you to perform *null-checks* afterwards??

Answer (score 1):

The easiest technique is to make the `.penalties(penalties)`
method null and empty list tolerant.

Note, the authors of both of the other answers appear to love NullPointerExceptions.

Here is some example code (with assumptions):

```
private List<Penalty> penaltiesList;

public QuoteDetailsBuilder penalties(final List<Penalty> newValue)
{
  if (CollectionUtils.isNotEmpty(newValue))
  {
    penaltiesList = newValue;
  }

  return this;
}
```

`CollectionUtils` is an apache utility for some null-safe collection functionality.

Comment: sure, love NPEs nearly as much as `StackOverflowError` ;-)

Answer (score 0):

Two "obvious" solutions come to my mind:

1. The builder supports an empty list in the correct way. You could maybe implement your own builder to do that which is just a wrapper around the original and doesn't call the original method `penalties` if the parameter is an empty list.
2. Use `if` as you would regularly do for "conditional" handling:

```
QuoteDetailsBuilder builder  = QuoteDetails.builder()
        .priceSummary(summary);
if ((null != penalties) && !penalties.isEmpty()) {
    builder = builder.penalties(penalties);
}
return builder.build();
```

(Of course in solution #2 the name of the builder class may vary depending on the implementation.)

Comment: added a `null` check, thx @DwB for the hint

Answer (score 0):

You can do it via the `isEmpty()` method to see if it's empty or not:

```java
.penalties(penalties.isEmpty() ? null : penalties)
```